# Angularjs cross view update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, observer-pattern

How to update one view data when a change happen in another view. Like view A.html have a chart and user updates graph data from B.html and goes back to A.html but is not showing the new data. You know in kockout.js has a Observables and dependency tracking, is that facility in angulerJs?

Comment: So, you have different controllers for your view components? Are they under the same route?

Comment: /**
 * Config for the router
 */
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'JS_REQUIRES',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $ocLazyLoadProvider, jsRequires) {

Comment: $stateProvider have different states for the routes like  // Set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('chartjs', 'chart.js', 'chatCtrl'),
        abstract: true
    }).state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/dashboard.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('d3', 'ui.knob', 'countTo', 'dashboardCtrl'),
        title: 'Dashboard',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Dashboard'
        }
    }) ......

Comment: Ummmm...maybe add that as an edit to the question. Much more readable. And also, will help people trying to get their heads around what you've been upto here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use events in combination with a service.

If you have two controllers for ViewA (`ControllerA`) and ViewB (`ControllerB`) and
the user updates the data in ViewB via `ControllerB`, you could fire an event to which
`ControllerA` is listening. To propagate the data from a view to another you can use a
service that stores the data. You could also send the data as a parameter in the
event broadcast.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g43Lfuu7/) provides a full example of how to do it.

An excerpt from the full code in the above example:

```
.service('CommonDataService', function () {
    this.data = null; // Our common data

    return this;
})
.controller('ControllerA', function ($rootScope, $scope, CommonDataService) {
    $scope.data = 'Initial data for view A';

    // User can update the data
    $scope.send = function () {
        CommonDataService.data = 'Data got updated from View A';
        $rootScope.$broadcast('data-update');
    }

    // Listen to the event
    $scope.$on('data-update', function () {
        $scope.data = CommonDataService.data;
    });
})
.controller('ControllerB', function ($rootScope, $scope, CommonDataService) {
    $scope.data = 'Initial data for view B';

    // User can update the data
    $scope.send = function () {
        CommonDataService.data = 'Data got updated from View B';
        $rootScope.$broadcast('data-update');
    }

    // Listen to the event
    $scope.$on('data-update', function () {
        $scope.data = CommonDataService.data;
    });
})
```